# How to implement a sliding animation on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a `UITableView` where each `UITableViewCell` has an image in the left. I have implemented a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` that moves the cell to the last position of the table view when it is swiped to the right.

I want to write an animation code that will increasingly move the cell to right until the user "releases" the finger (to give the impression that something is really happening).

How can I do that? Please tell me if I hadn't been clear enough. BTW, the Whatsapp app does this.

UPDATE: screenshot of what animation I'm talking about, from the Whatsapp app

[image]

UPDATE 2: Here is what I could do following @Matt's suggestion. However, I can't see a difference (the scrolling in action). Is this even correct?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the animation you want. Which part of Whatsapp does this?  Are you talking about horizontally sliding the cell (like the pull left to delete thing?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell's content is a horizontal scroll view, with the visible interface inside that. That's all there is to it. The slide is simply horizontal scrolling, just as with any scroll view.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I appreciate your tips but I'm kind of newbie on iOS and I'd love if you could provide some code guidance. Maybe which classes to go and all. I'm doing Swift and all I can find are 3-year-old, Objective-C code snippets. Thanks

Comment: Apple has explained very well in one of their WWDC videos on scroll views how this sort of sliding cell works (in the Mail app, for example). I suggest you watch those.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer but I suggest you hold off doing that until you see whether my advice actually gets you anywhere!

Comment: Hey @matt, please look my UPDATE 2 picture in the post. Tried doing what you suggested but can't notice a difference.

Comment: Well of course a scroll view cannot scroll until you have correctly configured its content size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75457/discussion-between-rodrigoalves-and-matt).